# How to add zero on the beginning of the double number

Tags: sql, oracle, format

I am trying to solve the following problem:

A double number, that is a result of dividing 2 double numbers, has on the beginning 0 and this is not displayed. (E.g. I would expect 0.537 but I can see only .0537) This is quite problem because the number is then converted to string and I need this zero on the beginning.

For the better imagination, please see the part of the code (which does not work for these numbers):

...

```
ELSE REPLACE(TRIM(to_char(ROUND(ab.price, 5)/ABS(ROUND(ab.position,5)), '999999.99999')),'.',',') END as Price
...
```

result: `,57300`

expected result: `0,57300`

Thank you for the answers.

M.

Comment: On a side note: Why do you use `DOUBLE`, an approximate data type? Do the values you store exceed 63 digits? You should avoid `DOUBLE` whenever possible. Use `NUMBER` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong format. `9` is for an optional digit. Use `0` for an obligatory one. You get the decimal separator matching your regional settings with `D`:

```
TO_CHAR( ROUND(ab.price, 5)/ABS(ROUND(ab.position, 5), '999990D99999' )
```

If you want the comma to be the decimal separator regardless of your settings, then specify this with `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS`:

```
TO_CHAR(
  ROUND(ab.price, 5)/ABS(ROUND(ab.position, 5), 
  '999990D99999', 
  'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.''' )
```